# How to get correct width of a UIView in UITableViewCell swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

I have created a UIView in IB in a Prototype cell and added constraints. The cell has a custom class. When I try to get the width of the UIView in cellForRowAtIndexPath it return 476 rather than 251. After reading SO on this subject, and the many answers, I have tried to call setNeedsLayout and layoutSubviews() in cellForRowAtIndexPath or in the subclass but neither returns the correct value. The height 20 is correct. Any help much appreciated!

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventCell") as! CustomResultsTVCell

    // cell.setNeedsLayout()

    let maxWidth = cell.barView.frame.width
    print("barview maxWidth is \(maxWidth)")
    // prints 476.0
```

[image: IB]

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? you have items inside not displaying correctly?

Comment: Have you checked th autolayout property of cell view. Is there any constraints for width ?

Comment: @jo3birdtalk - the issue is that the device its running on iphone5S has a screen width of 320. And maxwidth is showing as much greater than that.

Comment: @triple.s - there are no constraints set on the cells content view. They are all descendant constraints.

Comment: first, you should not bother anything about the screen size. Let auto layout do the work for you. With auto layout, regardless displaying on iPhone 5s, or displaying on iPad Pro size, it will not matter at all. Edit your question to show what are the items inside your cell so I can further help you.

Comment: hi @jo3birdtalk - I simplified everything and put it in this question. I hope u can help me...?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383143/width-of-uitableview-content-view-does-not-match-container/38384066#38384066

Answer (score 0):

You added a `trailing` and `leading` constraint of 55 and 10. This would make the width to be your parent view which in this case `CustomResultsTVCell` minus by 55 of `trailing` and 10 of `leading` space.

If you want to get a hardcoded 251 width, you should be setting a `Width` equal to 251 `constraint`.

Or if you actually think that you suppose to get a 251 width after applying the `trailing` and `leading` space, then i think the constraint for your `CustomResultsTVCell` or `UITableView` is not at the width that you are thinking. Maybe show us the constraint for these as well.

Comment: Hi Zac, I want the width to flex depending on the device its running, which is why I didn't hard code 251. I have cleared out the cell so the UIView is just has a leading and trailing constraint of 0 to the Content View. the TableVC is embedded in a ContainerView which is in a ViewContoller with simulated metrics size set to iPhone 4.7inch. So the UIView should be 375 wide. But now it prints at 584. If I change the simulated size to 4inch is prints as 359. How does the simulated size affect it when its running on a device 5S. Bizarre....

Comment: I am afraid simulated metrics size might be over-ridden here in this case. As generally we put in a view controller hierarchy which will resize it. Have you debug and check your width of ContainerView on run time?

Comment: yep, the container view is 320 width at run time. The TableVC is embedded in the container. For some reason the TableVC isn't picking up the same dimensions as the container....

Comment: got any other ideas Zac??

Comment: Could you update the question with more info like what items is in the cell and also maybe the constraint for the container view?

Comment: Hi Zac, I simplified and added more details in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383143/width-of-uitableview-content-view-does-not-match-container/38384066#38384066. Thanks if you can help...