# Width of UITableView content view does not match Container

Tags: swift, uitableview, containers

I have a TableVC embedded in a Container. The width of the Container running on an iPhone5 is 320. However the width of the ContentView in the TableView cell is 600. How can I make them match? (+/- padding). Am I missing a constraint? I have also tried setNeedsLayout() and layoutSubViews() in cellForRowAtIndexPath and in the custom cells subclass, but this doesn't seem to work either.

In the picture below, I want the width of the darkgrey to match the light grey (+- padding)

Any help much appreciated.....

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventCell") as! CustomResultsTVCell

    //        cell.setNeedsLayout()
    //        cell.layoutSubviews()
    //        cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    let barViewWidth = Float(cell.barView.frame.width)
    print("barview width is \(barViewWidth)")
// prints 584

    let contentViewWidth = cell.myContentView.frame.width
    print("contentView width is \(contentViewWidth)")
// prints 600
```

The CustomCell class is

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomResultsTVCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var myContentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var barView: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

//        super.layoutSubviews()
//        setNeedsLayout()
//        layoutSubviews()
    layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

[image: xcode]

Comment: Hi richc, can you show the constraint of your `containerView` and `tableView` as well? I just did a check and setup with constraints that i expected and it work. But if i remove the constraint for either `containerView` or the `tableView`, it will result in a 600 `width`. So i am pretty sure that one of the constraint is either not set or is wrong.

Comment: Hi Zac, the UITableViewController doesn't have any constraints set as I think it inherits from the ContainerView. How are you setting constraints for the UItableViewC?

Comment: Oh, my bad, i try it on a `tableView` in a `UIViewController`. However, i can embedding with a `UITableViewController` this time. The width is correct. Could you show your `containerView` constraint?

Comment: can you change your `My Content View` background colour to red, build and run to show me your simulator. u can crop things u want to hide.

Comment: Hi Jo, I moved all the sizing code to the cell subclass and got it to work. This issue still isn't fixed mind, but its good enough for now. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check property of your leading and trailing constraints. Make sure it unchecked **relative to margin** for both first item and second item.

see attached screenshots if it helps you.

Hope this will help you to fix your issue.

[image]

[image]

[image: xcode screenshot]

Comment: thanks Kuntal. I did as you suggest but the issue still remains. The TableViewCell width is still 600, and it needs to be the same as the Container at 320. Got any other ideas?

Comment: Did you also make constant 0?
is it possible to send me screenshot again?

Comment: Do you want cell width for specific reason?

Comment: hi - The constant is 0. I added a new screenshot for you. I need the cell width to have a flexible graphic in each cell. Thanks for any more suggestions.